# Copy exif info from one Uri to the other with the new Android Scoped Storage?

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I have two `Uri` from different files with schema "content" obtained by the Android SAF API and I need to copy exif information from one file to the other. The destination file was created by my app so I have granted write access to it.

With the `ContentResolver` I can obtain an `InputStream` that I can use to instantiate an `ExifInterface` from which I can extract the exif from the source `Uri`:

```
InputStream ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageInputUri);
ExifInterface originalExif = new ExifInterface(ins);
```

So far so good...
The problem is to write the exif info into the destination `Uri`. I can't do the same as I did with the source because an `ExifInferface` created with an `InputStream` is read-only and can't be used to save the exif info as [stated in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)).

How can I solve this problem and finally be able to copy those exif info from one file to another?

Comment: Cant you use public ExifInterface (FileDescriptor..... ? I wonder what this has to do with scoped storage yes or no.

Comment: @blackapps I don't have a FileDescriptor. I have an Uri obtained through SAF File picker (Scoped Storage) and since it is a "content" Uri and not a "file" Uri I don't think that it is possible to obtain a FileDescriptor from it. At least I don't know how I could do it. That's the real problem!

Comment: @blackapps Hummm... Now that you've mentioned it, I've made some tests and, as it seems, at least on my development environment the OutputStream created from this "content" Uri is indeed a ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream that extends a FileOutputStream from which I can obtain a FileDescriptor. Now the question is: If it actually works for solving the problem, can I relly on doing it in any Android device? Is it not dependent on device's Android implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one came with an answer but thanks to @blackapps comment I was able to find out the solution myself. I will post it here if someone else gets to this post searching for the answer for this same question.

It turns out that the `ExifInterface` has a constructor that receives a `FileDescriptor` as a parameter and it is possible to open a `FileDescriptor` from an `Uri` by using the `ContentResolver`. Then the solution is easy and the only extra care one needs in order to successfully open the `FileDescriptor` is to use the "rw" mode since the `ExifInterface` will need to read and write info and not just only write.

Here goes a sample code:

```java
InputStream ins = null;
ParcelFileDescriptor outFd = null;
try  {
    ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageInputUri);
    ExifInterface originalExif = new ExifInterface(ins);

    outFd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageOutputUri, "rw");
    ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(outFd.getFileDescriptor());
    copyExifAttributes(originalExif, newExif, width, height);

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    if (ins != null) {
        try {
            ins.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    if (outFd != null) {
        try {
            outFd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Be warned though that this code wont work on Android versions older than Lollipop (api 21). That's an `ExifInterface` limitation since it needs a seekable FileDescriptor in order to work and the `ExifiInterface` uses a [native call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) for doing this. Looking at the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os#lseek(java.io.FileDescriptor,%20long,%20int)) is possible to see that this native code is only available since Lollipop.

Comment: Hello,
Could you explain what is the copyExifAttributes function?

Comment: @frank, the method name is self explanatory, it is an auxiliar method that receives the original exif and the new created exif and it copies any required attribute from the original to the new exif. Then you just save it `newExif.saveAttributes()` and it is done.

Comment: @frank, It also override the width and height attributes in this case. But all those are details and aren't related to the main difficulty addressed by this question.